# how to implement 360 degree image viewer in ionic 1

Tags: ios, image, ionic-framework

I want to show a 360-degree image in my Ionic 1 App.

I found the [ionic-img-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-viewer) package for Ionic 2+, but I would need it to work in Ionic 1.

Is there a way to do it in Ionic 1?